# How to get keyboard control back after playing video in browser

Tags: video, keyboard-shortcuts, browser

After watching a video in a browser window (e.g. a youtube clip), my standard browser keyboard shortcuts don't work until I mouse-click somewhere else on the page.

Is there a way to do this without resorting to the mouse?

I'm using FF7 on Win7, but I've seen the same issue on Chrome/Mac.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IE. Internet Explorer has no problem with keyboard shortcuts even while playing any embedded content say flash.
The default behavior in all the other major browser prevent this from happening.

As a dirty workaround press Alt+Tab to move to some other window and come back to browser window, the keyboard shortcuts should work then as the focus would have shifted from the flash video element to the browser address bar again.